# I am getting in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python

```
s = raw_input("string: ")

if ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u") in s:
    print s.count("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
else:
    print ("No vowels")
```

this is my code, essentially i want someone to type in a string and for this program to count the amount of vowels. Why doesnt this work?

Comment: Does it not say the exact location of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet it's trying to see if the tuple, ('a','e'...) is in the string, not the items individually.  Iterate:

```
count = 0
for letter in 'aeiou':
   if letter in s:
       count += s.count(letter)
print count
```

Comment: I made some edits, but the solutions I put give a final count, not a true or false, yes?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems like for loop is the way to go rather then the if-else statements.

Comment: Sorry, I been using numpy arrays so long I forgot you couldn't sum a list that way.  I'll delete that second form

Answer (score 2):

Your code checks if a tuple `("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")` is inside string `s` which of course is not existed.
If you need keep track of what vowel has been repeated how many times, you should do like this:

```
In[22]: s = 'aiuo hohoho'
In[23]: vowel_count = {i:s.count(i) for i in 'aiueo'}
In[24]: vowel_count
Out[24]: {'a': 1, 'e': 0, 'i': 1, 'o': 4, 'u': 1}
```

It gives you a dict of `vowel:counts`, so you can get the count of any vowel like this:

```
In[25]: vowel_count['o']
Out[25]: 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether it's a subset:

```
if set("aeiou") <= set(s):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a dict to remember the count of vowels:

```
s = raw_input("string: ")

aeiou_dict = {'a':0,'e':0,'i':0,'o':0,'u':0}

for char in s:
   if char in 'aeiou':
      aeiou_dict[char] += 1
   else:
      pass

print aeiou_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way. Every element in the final list is the count of vowels you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Take this for an example
a = 'aeiouaeioujjj'
print [a.count(item) for item in 'aeiou']
```

OUTPUT:

```
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet using Python's built-in `sum`, which relies on Python's equivalence of True and 1:

```
>>> s = "sldkjfwoqpwefjsfueiof"
>>> num_vowels = sum(c in "aeiou" for c in s.lower())
>>> print num_vowels
6
```

For every character in s, evaluate whether it is in "aeiou" or not. If it is, this evaluates to True, equivalent to the value 1. Characters not in "aeiou" evaluate to False, equivalent to 0.  `sum` adds these all up, the result will tell you how many characters in the input string satisfy the vowel condition.  (Don't forget to convert the input string to lower case as shown by calling `.lower()`, else you will accidentally skip over vowels that are capitalized.)